# Possible to link Ga4 roll up property to Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am wodering if it is possible to link a Ga4 roll up property to Big query?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google help center article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11526039?hl=en), "Currently, roll-up properties can only be directly linked to Google Ads. All data from source-property product integrations is available in the roll-up property."

I would imagine that this would be an option in the future along with other product links such as Ad Manager and Search Console given that a standard GA4 property can link to various products today.